# Quickbooks integration using QWC to PHP Server (API)

Tags: php, api, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I'm trying to set up a connection to my QBD Company using the QWC program so I can add/update/pull information from my Company using PHP on a different server with CURL. I downloaded and installed Quickbooks enterprise solution 13 and quickbooks web connection, and created my .QWC file. When I try and authenticate it, It requests for a Password which I don't have. Could you help me with this Issue?

Other Issues:
In the QWC file it requests an AppURL and a SupportURL, What kind of information should be on these pages? I believe this might be a big problem as well because currently they link to blank PHP pages.

My Goal is to set up a connections between my server and QWC so when I need to I can use PHP to build an appropriate string and send it to my QBD<-QWC.

Answer (score 1):

The Web Connector is unusual in that it's "backwards" from what most normal web services are. Instead of you using CURL to call out to QuickBooks, the Web Connector expects that *it is going to (use the .NET equivalent of CURL) to call out to you* instead.

We have a detailed explanation of how this process works on our [QuickBooks Web Connector overview](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector) wiki page.

Your best bet is probably not to start from scratch - instead, try the existing [PHP QuickBooks library](http://consolibyte.com/quickbooks-open-source/):

- Main link: http://consolibyte.com/quickbooks-open-source/
- Download: http://consolibyte.com/downloads/quickbooks-php-devkit/

The place to start is the [QuickBooks + PHP Quick-Start](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Quick-Start) guide from the wiki:

- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Quick-Start

That will get you up and running and adding customers to QuickBooks quickly and easily.

**Some other specifics:**

> When I try and authenticate it, It requests for a Password which I
>   don't have.

You have to define that username/password - it's what the Web Connector will use to authenticate against the web service that you set up (see the quick-start guide - it walks you through creating that web service endpoint, example_web_connector.php)

> In the QWC file it requests an AppURL and a SupportURL

If you follow the quick-start guide, it will be something like http://www.your-website.com/path/to/example_web_connector.php